# How to match across dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, one is a Free Trade Agreement dataset that contains many columns, the columns c1 to c91 denote different countries part of a particular Free Trade Agreement, as shown below:
[FTA data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeQ89.png)

FTA data e.g.

```
No   Base_treaty   entry_type               c1          c2            c3
1     1            treaty             Afghanistan     India           NA
2     2            treaty                Algeria      Egypt          Ghana
3     3            treaty                Algeria      Angola         Benin
4     4            treaty                Egypt        Jordan         Morocco
5     5            treaty                Albania      Bulgaria         NA
6     6            treaty                Albania      Croatia          NA
```

The other data frame contains trade data between two particular countries, i and j. [Trade Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqrSv.png)

```
   inventor_ctry_i   authority_ctry_j           
1    Albania            Bulgaria         
2    Albania            Croatia          
3    Algeria             Angola        
4    Algeria            Belgium         
5    Algeria            France          
6    Andorra            Turkey          
7    Andorra          United States   
8    Anguilla           Germany         
9    Anguilla         Switzerland     
10    Anguilla        United States
```

Desired output:

```
No   Base_treaty   entry_type         matched ctry1   matched ctry2       
 3     3            treaty                Algeria      Angola         
 5     5            treaty                Albania      Bulgaria         
 6     6            treaty                Albania      Croatia
```

I want to be able to find countries i and j in trade data that show up in the same row somewhere in between c1 to c91 of the FTA data. **If both are present in a particular row, extract the 2 countries from the row in FTA, keeping no, base treaty and entry type column intact.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenation is a bit different from the merging techniques you saw above. With merging, you can expect the resulting dataset to have rows from the parent datasets mixed in together, often based on some commonality. Depending on the type of merge, you might also lose rows that don’t have matches in the other dataset.

With concatenation, your datasets are just stitched together along an axis — either the row axis or column axis. Visually, a concatenation with no parameters along rows would look like this:

```
concatenated = pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Please refer to this [link](https://realpython.com/pandas-merge-join-and-concat/) for more understanding and clearance of code.